# Unable to connect to Azure Redis cache in C# using StackExchange.Redis (timeout errors)

Tags: .net, windows, azure, stackexchange.redis

I am integrating an Azure Redis cache (Basic C0 for dev) into one of our .Net systems (.Net 4.6.1) and using the StackExchange.Redis v2.6.90 client library. This is all running in Windows environments (10 for local dev, Server 2019 Std for test)

I have created a basic wrapper to handle the connection for me:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace Rimes.Azure
{
    public class RedisCache
    {
        private ConnectionMultiplexer _redis;

        private void Initialize(ConfigurationOptions options)
        {
            // Azure requires TLS 1.2 but .Net uses TLS 1.1 by default
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
        }

        public RedisCache(string endPoint, string token, bool useSsl = true, bool abortOnConnectFail = true)
        {
            var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(endPoint);
            options.Password = token;
            options.Ssl = useSsl;
            options.AbortOnConnectFail = abortOnConnectFail;

            Initialize(options);
        }

        public string Get(string key)
        {
            IDatabase db = _redis.GetDatabase();
            return db.StringGet(key);
        }

        public bool Set(string key, string value, int timeToLive)
        {
            IDatabase db = _redis.GetDatabase();
            return db.StringSet(key, value, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeToLive));
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly from my local dev machine (surprise! I know, one of **those** issues) with excellent performance. From the test server it doesn't work at all - the only response is a `RedisTimeoutException` (gets, sets and I believe also instantiation, given the time it takes to instantiate):

```
Exception type: RedisTimeoutException 
Exception message: Timeout performing PSETEX (5000ms), inst: 0, qu: 1, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, last-in: 0, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 2, async-ops: 1, serverEndpoint: xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, conn-sec: n/a, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: xxx(SE.Redis-v2.6.90.64945), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=12,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=12,Max=32767), v: 2.6.90.64945 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server, T defaultValue)
at Rimes.Azure.RedisCache.Set(String key, String value, TimeSpan expiry)
```

I have gone through the suggestions in the link provided in the error message and read tonnes of material around the place, but it doesn't appear that any of the advice on what to look for is valid in my situation

What I have tried:

- Boosted timeout from the default 5000ms to 30000ms - No change
- psping, to validate connection to Azure - This is successful
- Checked firewall settings, both on local server and on Azure - No firewall config in Azure and local server is configured to allow outgoing connections
- Checked .Net versions - Actually running 4.8 in both environments. Only difference here appears to be my local machine running 4.8.04084 and server running 4.8.03761
- Checked with network team, to verify no external factors - They can't find anything
- Re-developed in Python, using redis 3.5.3 library - The cache works perfectly here from both machines

Based on the above, I know the issue exists somewhere in my .Net environment, but my experience here is limited and I am unsure where to go with this now. I welcome any suggestions!

**Update:**

I did have this working on the test server on Friday 14th Feb and it was not working on Monday 17th Feb. Looking around I found two MS Security updates for .Net that were released to fix a critical security update on the 14th - KB5022504 and KB5022782

Removal of these updates made no difference, but it did get me looking into .Net updates and it seems different Group Policy settings cause different update practices. On our servers, we only get security updates and on my dev machine I only get feature updates

**Update:**

Opening and using the non-SSL port on Azure Redis works. Dialing back to TLS 1.0 also works. Setting TLS to anything higher fails, with the following output in the extra logging:

```
11:09:02.9964: Allowing 1 endpoint(s) 00:00:05 to respond...
11:09:02.9964: Awaiting 1 available task completion(s) for 5000ms, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=32763,Min=10,Max=32767)
11:09:03.0241: Configuring TLS
11:09:03.0554: Connection failed: xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 (Subscription, AuthenticationFailure): AuthenticationFailure on xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Subscription, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.6.96.30123
11:09:03.0554: > A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
11:09:03.0554: > The function requested is not supported
11:09:03.0554: xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: OnConnectedAsync completed (Disconnected)
...
11:09:03.1178: Endpoint Summary:
11:09:03.1178:   xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v4.0.0, primary; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Disconnected; sub: Disconnected; not in use: DidNotRespond
11:09:03.1178:   xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3
11:09:03.1178:   xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
11:09:03.1178: Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
11:09:03.1178: Starting heartbeat...
11:09:08.1781: Encountered exception: StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: The timeout was reached before the message could be written to the output buffer, and it was not sent, command=SUBSCRIBE, timeout: 5000, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: CheckingForTimeout, rs: NotStarted, ws: Initializing, in: 0, last-in: 0, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 1, serverEndpoint: xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, conn-sec: n/a, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: LDOKTATEST01(SE.Redis-v2.6.96.30123), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=32761,Min=10,Max=32767), v: 2.6.96.30123 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebugge
```

Based on the SSPI failure after configuring TLS, I decided to remove the `SecurityProtocol` setting and try configuring .Net to use TLS 1.2 through the registry. **This works**

What I'm missing now, is how to set the TLS version to 1.2 in code, so this works without having to set registry keys

Comment: Try below links,
Use Azure Cache for Redis in .NET Framework (document_link: 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache.md)
Use Azure Cache for Redis in .NET Core (document_link: 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-core-quickstart.md)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.1. Adding the following to the existing connection string solve the issue: `sslProtocols=tls12`. I'm using StackExchange.Redis v 1.2.6 (at the time the latest version supported for .Net Framework).

Also, make sure your application is using TLS 1.2. In C# this can be done with the following code:
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

When deployed to Azure, make sure the configuration of the resources is set to use TLS 1.2 as well.

Reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-remove-tls-10-11#net-framework

Comment: I'm already doing this and it works just fine in my dev environment. It is not working on our servers (test or production). The only way I can get it working is by setting the system-wide default TLS version to 1.2 in the registry (which I was hoping to avoid, but IT managed to get this change to our environment rolled out quickly)